# Conversion amount to text Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Can you please guide me to a tutorial that will allow me to convert an amount into text. Because I tried to create some functions but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo suggests to use num2words python library.